# What house at Hogwarts was Mundungus Fletcher sorted into?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I have two personal theories;

- Fletcher is a Slytherin (because he is involved in many illegal activities).
- Fletcher is a Hufflepuff (because he was deeply loyal to Albus Dumbledore).

I don't think he is a Ravenclaw (because he is somewhat a dimwit), neither a Gryffindor (because he is a coward).

**What house at Hogwarts was Mundungus Fletcher in?**

Comment: Well, Peter Pettigrew was sorted into Gryffindor, and he was pretty cowardly. Also, when was it revealed that Mundungus Fletcher had a crush on Dumbledore?

Comment: @Adamant - Edited to "is loyal to" which far better characterises their relationship

Comment: @Valorum - Perhaps some obscure publication suggests that Mundungus did have a crush on him, though.

Comment: @Adamant - Only fanfic. Note that this is a book series of more than a million words with zero openly gay characters

Comment: I'm at a loss why people think this needs closing as "opinion-based".

Comment: Perhaps none of the four houses will admit to having him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His house status is canonically unknown, but we do know from this image from *[Harry Potter Limited Edition - A Guide to the Graphic Arts Department: Posters, Prints, and Publications from the Harry Potter Films](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/A_Guide_to_the_Graphic_Arts_Department:_Posters,_Prints,_and_Publications_from_the_Harry_Potter_Films)* (and seen very briefly in *Order of the Phoenix*) that he went to Hogwarts.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Apart from the correct answer obviously being "we don't know", I find it rather hilarious that a bloody government Ministry can't even find out a) what country a bloke was born in who's got an East End accent as thick as the Thames in summer or b) what house he was in at Hogwarts. As if ***no one at all*** in the Ministry is his age and house affiliation!

Comment: @elemtilas - I personally suspect that like lots of children coming from families where criminality is tolerated, he created very little impression on those around him and left school early.

Comment: Britain measures height and weight in inches and lbs?

Comment: @Alex - Height in feet + inches, absolutely. Weight in pounds is not *abnormal*, but stones and pounds is more common.